# Manager Layer vs Service Layer

Tags: jakarta-ee, service-layer, 3-tier

In the 3 tier architecture there is Presentation/Web Layer, Service Layer and DB Layer. However in a recent project I worked on I saw a Manager Layer which is new to me. Can you please explain the difference between Service Layer/ Classes vs Manager Layer/ Classes?

Also please suggest some good books for learning 3 - tier architecture and related patterns. (For Java/ Java EE applications)

Comment: Isn't that manager actually the so called `Service Manager`? AKA `Service Locator`? Which is a kind of global scope where you can get your services from?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per me : Manager Layer is a part of Service Layer in small applications. In complex applications we need to provide Manager Layer on the top of Service Layer.

Normally we don't need both in simple applications with a single UI, in this case we only manage Business Logic Layer / Manager Layer. In case of multiple UIs and Clients we divide Service Layer in 2 parts to handle UIs and to provide another services in application.

Comment: Thanx for your answer Pandey. Can you please suggest some good books on this subject?

Comment: Try this : [Matin Fowler : Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture](http://martinfowler.com/books/eaa.html)

Answer (score 2):

Manager layer is actually used as a delegation component.
The 3 tier architecture that you read is correct.
The concept of manager comes up when a layer actually gets complicated; you like to use a separate component in each layer to do the activity of a delegator.Usually called a Manager.

So the new layer that you have heard of does not break the concept of 3 tier architecture you have read so far.

Comment: Thanx Ayusman. Any good books on this subject to for me to study further?